# Lower Bound on Probabilities in GLM

Tags: r, glm

Is there a way to bound the estimated probabilities that are produced by a GLM (logistic regression)? Currently, my GLM estimates coefficients for the following equation:

log(p/1-p) = Intercept + Coefficients*ExplanatoryVars

But this allows p to fall anywhere on [0,1]. I would like to bound p to [0.25,1]

My glm code is simply:

```
myglm <- glm(tf ~ qsample + studentsample, family = binomial)
```

where qsample and studentsample are factors. 
      tf is a vector of 0 and 1's.

Comment: I'm having troubles imagining a statistical justification for this.

Comment: I dont think that this is what a logistic/probit regression is designed for. They try to estimate the propability of taking option 1 over option 0. Restricting this propability would just be faking the result: What would be the interpretation of the resulting propabilities?

Comment: I was worried that the logistic regression wouldn't apply here too. Basically, I am trying to predict whether the response to questions will be correct or incorrect (hence logistic regression), however, the question contains multiple choice (4 options), therefore, the probability should never be less than 0.25. I'm not sure how to implement this though.

Comment: I don't think it's worth worrying about. You'll probably find that the bulk of your data will result in estimated probabilities > 0.25, and it shouldn't be hard to think of trick questions where everyone goes for the obvious, wrong, answer.

Comment: What probability is to be expected simply is a matter of the data. Restricting the parameter space in frequentist analyses will only hurt the model and do you no good. If you're looking for a way to put more emphasis on a certain range of expected values, then you should go for Bayesian data analyses. Prior knowledge regarding the model coefficients can then be formalized by means of a probability density to be chosen by the user.

Comment: Thanks all. I think the Bayesian route is the only option here.